# Android: Unable to implement search on a lazyloading listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a custom listview in my app. I use an http request to get the data in JSON format. There is an asynctask to load the entire data (except the images) for the listview.

In on onpostexecute() of this asyntask, I call up another asynctask to fetch the images for the listview.

Now I am trying to implement a search feature on the listview using a textchangedlistener

The problem is with the images getting loaded in the background, I often run into null pointer exception.

Can anyone suggest me a way to get rid of this. What I am doing currently is that I am not showing the searchbox edittext till the images are loaded. But this makes the user wait a lot, especially for long lists.

The entire code is too long to post. So, I am just pasting here the brief outline of it. Do let me know if you need anything else. I ll do that as well.

```
public class abcd extends Activity {
    ListView todlistview;
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> cnt = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> searchResults; /

    .
    .




     /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{


        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        .
        .
        .

            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), cnt, com.example.promoapp.R.layout.textviewfield, from, to);

            return adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> (cnt);

            // Setting adapter for the listview
            todlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                .
        .


        ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();
                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm); 
            }
        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        Dialog dil;
        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream=null;
                  .


                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {

        }



    }


    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

        String searchString=Search.getText().toString();
                int textLength=searchString.length();               

                searchResults.clear();

                for(int i=0;i<cnt.size();i++)
                {
                    String placeName=cnt.get(i).get("country").toString();

                    if(textLength<=placeName.length()){
                        //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                        if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(placeName.substring(0,textLength))){
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),placeName,1).show();
                            searchResults.add(cnt.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }

                String[] from = { "country","flag","details"};
                 int[] to = { com.example.promoapp.R.id.tv_country,com.example.promoapp.R.id.iv_flag,com.example.promoapp.R.id.tv_country_details};
                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), searchResults, com.example.promoapp.R.layout.textviewfield, from, to);
                 todlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
              }
     };


}
```

Comment: add your logcat errors!!

Comment: Unless you are specifically initializing cnt List and HashMaps within it to empty objects, value object `Object` will be null.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was planning to post this question a couple of days back. I have made many other changes in the code, am getting other errors and do not have a logcat for it now. 

But the error I got was null pointer exception .. index x requested  with a size of y .. I ll try to replicate the error and post the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wouldn't perform heavy task like image loading in **onPostExecute** because this method works on UI thread. You just block UI with you ImageLoaderTask. I would try to load images along with everything else in the first AsyncTask. The problem is that you are searching and modifying list at the same time. Try to do image loading **onBackground** of the ListViewLoaderTask

Comment: ImageLoaderTask is also an AsynTask. it doesn't run on UI.

Comment: @el_bhm From what I've seen, it does run on UI. I had the same task as 1)load json 2) parse image. And yes, parsing onPostExecute, even with AsyncTask does slow down ui. The problem is that you modify adapter when searching, generally

Comment: The onpostexecute() method calls another asynctask which does the task of loading images in the background. So, the UI thread does not get blocked. And the reason to keep two asynctask is that the images are secondary and we think the user would like to get the other details first while the the images are shown later